# Apriori algorithm: Having frequent (k-1)-subsets implies being frequent?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I have been staring at the following line in a book describing the Apriori algorithm for mining frequent itemsets, and I can not seem to grasp it

*Note that given a candidate k-itemset, we only need to check if its (k-1)-subsets are frequent since the Apriori algorithm uses a level-wise search strategy.*

In the above, candidate means being a potential frequent k-itemset.

It is clear that the (k-1)-subsets of frequent k-itemset are frequent, but I don't see the other implication even with all the (k-1)-subsets being frequent. But perhaps I am reading in a wrong way ?

Comment: You might want to provide some context, so that people not familiar with this particular algorithm could help.

Comment: I agree with the question -- you only need to check itemsets whose subsets are frequent, but you still need to count the elements in the larger itemset.  I think there is probably some context missing like @Nikita said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is clear that the (k-1)-subsets of frequent k-itemset are frequent, but I don't see the other implication even with all the (k-1)-subsets being frequent."

You are right, the other implication is not true. The (k-1) subsets are used to generate the k-itemsets you need to test for frequentness, or support (as the original paper calls it). You need to test for support for the k-itemsets generated from the (k-1)-subsets.

The original paper is quite readable and available [here](http://rakesh.agrawal-family.com/papers/vldb94apriori.pdf). Page 4 column 1 has an example which makes the idea here quite clear.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the reference which has a more clear and precise description than the text book we are using for the course. In the book they must have meant to say that having a non-frequent subset implies being non-frequent and therefore a candidate can be pruned if it has a non-frequent subset and otherwise support has to be found.

Comment: That's how I'd understand it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The other implication is not true.   But if one subset is not frequent then the itemset will not be frequent. The APriori algorithm perform the subset check to eliminate some infrequent itemset. But after that, it still need to check the support of each candidate. To do that, the Apriori algorithm will scan the database.

If you want a better description of Apriori, I suggest to check this book chapter:

http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch6.pdf

It explains Apriori, FPGrowth and association rule mining in very simple terms. It is easier to read than the original Apriori article.